# How can I print method results to a TextField in GUI?

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a binary-to-decimal-and-back GUI converter.

I have the working code, and I figured out how to apply the Binary-to-Decimal part in GUI, but I have trouble with Decimal-to-Binaryone.

Let me first explain what I did and what worked for Bin-to-Dec:

I used this method (in the area sort of under main, because it didn't work in the area of the action button, if you know what I mean):

```
public int stringToDec(String inputBin) {

    int decimal = 0;
    int power = 0;
    while (inputBin.length() > 0) {
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(inputBin.charAt((inputBin.length()) - 1) + "");
        decimal += temp * Math.pow(2, power++);
        inputBin = inputBin.substring(0, inputBin.length() - 1);

    }
    return decimal;
}
```

And in the "area of the action button" I converted the result to a String and assigned it to a text field where I want my result to show up:

```
String intstring = Integer.toString(stringToDec(inputBin)); 
resultDecField.setText(intstring);
```

And it worked. But when I tried to apply the same logic to Decimal-to-Binary I ran into a lot of problems. 
I use this for Dec-to-Bin conversion:

```
public int decToBinary(int inputDec) {
    do {
        System.out.print(inputDec % 2);
        inputDec /= 2;
    } while (inputDec > 0);

}
```

But I can't just substitute `System.out` with `setText`. I think I need to capture the result in a variable somehow and then assign it to a field. Am I right? But how and what variable? Maybe an array? But I have no idea how to do it and can't find anything online. I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you tell me in which format you need to show your data(i.e. sample text/data which would be shown)

Comment: I'd just like to display it in the result field in, you know, numbers :).  Doesn't matter if it's a String or ints or a double or whatnot.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we're more able to help you. Are you using swing?

Comment: This is what the working part looks like: http://oi61.tinypic.com/idi23a.jpg

Comment: Ok, wait, I'll make a MCVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code and it should work

```
public int decToBinary(int inputDec) {
    String returnVal = "";
    do {
        returnVal = returnVal + (inputDec % 2);
        inputDec /= 2;
    } while (inputDec > 0);
    return Integer.parseInt(returnVal);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I was in the middle of making a MCVE, but it's not needed anymore, because this worked! Thank you so much, Vivek! I kind of had something like that in mind, but I had no idea about the syntax because I'm really new to this.  Now I see how it's done. Great example. :)

Comment: Ok I might've spoken too soon. It only works in the binary result consists of 1's. It skips the zeros. :/ But I think it's the problem with my initial code.